# change Magicsuggest max selection warning message

Tags: jquery, asp.net, magicsuggest

when i add 1 employee in magic suggest then it will give a warning message
 "You cannot choose more than 1 items"
that message i want to change and do it "You cannot choose more than 1 Employee"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the maxSelectionRenderer. Example:

```
$('#msDivId').magicSuggest({
    maxSelection: 1,
    maxSelectionRenderer: function () {
        return "You cannot choose more than 1 Employee";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `Property` `maxSelection : 1` or set to `N` based on your requirement.

Comment: i want to remove this line